# .Net Xml Serialization: how to collapse misc children nodes to text?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I'd like to use XmlSerializer to deserialize the following structure:

```
<modules>

  <module name="1">
     <config>
       <miscNodes1/>  ...
     </config>
  </module>

  <module name="2">
     someConfigString1;someConfigString2; 
  </module>


</modules>
```

to .net classes like that:

```
[XmlRoot("modules")]
class Config 
{
  [XmlElement("module");
  public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

class Module
{
  [XmlAttribute("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [???]
  public string Config { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to collapse miscellaneous children nodes inside ./modules/module to string:
`"<config><miscNodes1/></module>"` and `"someConfigString1;someConfigString2;"`  (just as if I call InnerXml for element)

XmlText doesn't help me.

How can I do that ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you show two very different layouts in the xml; what rules are you thinking of applying to choose between them here?

Comment: it doesn't really matter for me. I just want to collapse xml nodes to string somehow (as if I call InnerXml) in one case and get straightforward data in the second case.

Comment: It matters, because your XML is poorly/inconsistently structured.  So there is no way to automatically do what you are asking - you'll have to manually parse and collapse things yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XmlAnyElement attribute on array of XmlNode, like this:
[XmlAnyElement]
public XmlNode[] Config { get; set; }

Comment: It's easier to use: [XmlElement("config")] public XmlElement Config { get; set; }